# Trying to produce a graph with transparent background and white axis and labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is my current code, I'm trying to produce a graph with a transparent background and white axis and labels to put on a dark background but am getting endless errors.
[image]

The numbers on the axis have gone white but not the actual axis or the labels. Would really appreciate any help thank you!

```
p1 <- ggplot(plot_1, (aes(x= cover, y= abundance, color=Type, shape=Type))) +
 scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 200))+
 scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 50))+
 theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent", colour = NA),  plot.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent", colour = NA))+
         theme(axis.text.x = element_text(colour = "white")) +
 theme(axis.text.y = element_text(colour = "white"), element_text( color = "white"))+
 xlab("% surface algal cover")+
 ylab("Zooplankton abundance")
p1 + geom_point( size = 3) + geom_smooth(method=lm,level= 0.5, fullrange=TRUE)+
 scale_color_manual(name="Type",values=c("Blue3","Yellow2"))
```

Comment: Could you please share your data using `dput`?

Comment: You've got an extra `, element_text( color = "white")` in the last `theme`

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want? I set the background to "black" temporarily to see the white bits.  You had a stray `, element_text( color = "white")` causing the error.

I've used a little made-up data to test this. It's always better to share some of your sample data where possible as sometimes the issues are in the data.

You can also combine the `theme` lines into one statement and use `axis.text` instead of both `axis.text.x` and `axis.text.y`.

`axis.line` will let you colour the axis itself.

```r
library(tidyverse)

# Made-up data
plot_1 <- tribble(~cover, ~abundance, ~Type,
        1, 1, 1,
        2, 2, 2,
        3, 3, 2,
        2, 2, 1,
        3, 3, 2,
        4, 3, 2
        ) |> 
  mutate(Type = factor(Type))

ggplot(plot_1, aes(cover, abundance, color = Type, shape = Type)) +
  geom_point(size = 3) +
  geom_smooth(method = lm, level = 0.5, fullrange = TRUE) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 200)) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 50)) +
  scale_color_manual(name = "Type", values = c("Blue3", "Yellow2")) +
  labs(x = "% surface algal cover", y = "Zooplankton abundance") +
  theme(
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent", colour = NA),
    plot.background = element_rect(fill = "black", colour = NA),
    axis.line = element_line(colour = "white"),
    axis.text = element_text(colour = "white")
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-05-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>